# How to fix endpoint where Endpoint Administrators lost privileges by accident?

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-devops-server-2019

By mistake, I deleted Endpoint Administrators group privileges from a service connection endpoint in Azure DevOps Server 2019. Thus, I lost administrative privileges to that endpoint, even though I am a project administrator. I can see no users in Administrator role on that endpoint. The creator of the endpoint is not listed among the remaining users.

The [docs of service connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=classic) are not helpful. I tried asking a colleague who is in the Team Foundation Administrators group, but he sees the Add button disabled, too, so he cannot add the group back.

Do I have to re-create the endpoint and change all pipelines to use the new one? Or is there a way to fix the old one?

[image: Screenshot of the Service Connections menu, showing that the endpoint has just two users, both in role User, along with the message: You do not have permission to manage this service connection's roles. One of the users is the group Release Administrators.]

Answer (score 1):

> Do I have to re-create the endpoint and change all pipelines to use
>   the new one?

Nope, not sure the permission configuration in your collection, because i can also even if I am not the one of project admin. But the user who is member of `Project Collection Administrators`(**note**, this member **must be member of** `Project Collection Administrators`) could do this without trouble.

---

If it is still not suitable, try with below api to add it:

```
PUT https://{instance}/{collection}/_apis/securityroles/scopes/distributedtask.serviceendpointrole/roleassignments/resources/{project id}_{resource id}
```

Request body:

```
[{"roleName":"Administrator","userId":"abxxxxxxxf8f7"}]
```

**Key Point:**

`{project id}_{resource id}`: This parameter which after resource is the **combination** of `project id` and `resource id`. For `project id`, you could catch it by this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0). And for `resource id`, you could get it from the URL blank directly while clicking on that specific service connection.

`userId`: This is the id of `Endpoint Administrators`. You can get it from `F12` while clicking this group in the page of `https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_settings/security`.

Comment: I tried the API call under my account, from browser's console when logged in. The result was a 403 response.

Comment: `{"$id":"1","customProperties":{"Descriptor":"System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity;{sid}","IdentityDisplayName":"{name}","Token":"endpoints/{proj id}/{ep id}","RequestedPermissions":2,"NamespaceId":"49b48001-ca20-4adc-8111-5b60c903a50c"},"innerException":null,"message":"Access Denied: {name} needs the following permission(s) on the resource endpoints/{proj id}/{ep id} to perform this action: Administer Endpoint","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Security.AccessCheckException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi","typeKey":"AccessCheckException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`

Comment: Will try the same with the colleague. Just sent him the code I used to execute the request (Fetch API call executed from the console of Google Chrome with logged in user).

Comment: BTW, I had to append `?api-version=5.0-preview.1` to the URI and add `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Comment: @Palec. wow...so much contents. How great you shared me the second comment. It is very useful! Based on this message and the error code 403, you and one of your colleague can not add users to service connection just because your corresponding permission is limited. Ensure the account that the message mentioned are one of endpoint administrator

Comment: As I wrote in the question, my account is a member of Project Administrators. Project Administrators group is a member of Endpoint Administrators. The problem is that Endpoint Administrators do not have administrative privileges to that specific endpoint anymore -- that's what I want to fix and that's what this question is about.

Comment: @Palec, I got it. Forgive my mislead words. In my comment, what I point is your endpoint role not that group. If I am a administrator role of this endpoint, **add** button is available for me. But if my role is just a user, same with your colleague, it is gray.

Comment: Now I probably get you original comment. You mean that the request to the API should be sent from an account that already has administrative privileges to that endpoint. But that's the bummer -- there are no administrators of the endpoint at all. The Endpoint Administrators group was the last one and I accidentally removed it.

Comment: @Palec, Yes. And you mean no account left in that service connection? Or nobody whose role is administrator left? Strange, as normal, the creator would not be removed and its role should always be administrator. If possible, I appreciate you could share a screenshot about this service connection. For security, you can cover some sensitive content.

Comment: I added the screenshot in the question. The creator of the connection is not among the users listed there.

Comment: @Palec, okay.. If what you used is VSTS, our team may help you to add admin from backend. But it is TFS, you can try to contact the admin of the machine that TFS server located. And suggest this man do it.

Comment: As I indicated by a tag, we are using Azure DevOps Server 2019 (the renamed TFS), specifically its Update 1. I found out that the colleague is actually admin of the whole TFS (added that to the question). So maybe it could not be achieved through the UI, nor through the API? Is there another way? Maybe creating a new endpoint for the same service would be easier, ultimately.

Comment: @Palec.Yeah, I saw. I hopefully it is VSTS so that I could help directly. I'm not sure how the creator was removed from this endpoint on your side. I'm afraid you'd better create new endpoint though this would be very trouble, because lots of pipeline need be changed. I need suggest, please at least retain one endpoint role like creator here.